# ContentObserver used for SMS

Tags: android, sms, contentobserver

I'm trying to extract the sent SMS. I know there is no BroadcastReciver for this. So I've found that I can use ContentObserver to listen changes in the db.

How can I implement this? My objective is to **get only the new sms sent** and send it via POST on the DB

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code fragment to do this. The key is to use a selection that looks only for "type = outgoing messages".

Also since the content DB can get triggered by any change, keep track (somehow) of what has already been processed.

```
int THREAD_ID = 0, ADDRESS = 1, DATE = 2, TYPE = 3, BODY = 4, INCOMING = 1, OUTGOING = 2, UNKNOWN = -1;

String[] smsProjection = new String[] {"thread_id", "address", "date", "type", "body"};

ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, smsProjection, "type = ? AND date > ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(OUTGOING), Long.toString(lastOutgoingSmsTime)}, null);
```

Comment: Hi @PVS, where do you get the value for lastOutgoingSmsTime?

Comment: lastOutgoingSmsTime is an app variable, that defines what "new" means to the app. Everytime you extract a set of SMS, just updated this timestamp for the next query. You'll have to handle it somehow the very first time.

Comment: got it. I stored the messageId to prefernces when ever a message is sent. then i compare the messageIds to check if its new.