# Receiving system intents in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'd like to receive system **intents android.intent.action.SEND_MESSAGE** and **com.android.mms.transaction.MESSAGE_SENT** using broadcast receivers. I know how to use receivers but I never seem to catch these intents when an SMS is sent.

These intents are used by the messaging app and they can be found in its source on github.

Help.

Edit: 
I get no errors. I'm unable to catch these intents when an SMS is sent. 
And I chanced upon these intents in the default messaging app source.

Comment: You can't. See the `SmsReceiver` class

Comment: what's your error exactly..?

Comment: @pankaj, isn't there any way to listen to these broadcasts? Why can't my app do it if the messaging app can?

Comment: I doubt android would let a rogue app listen in on SMS messages.

Comment: @segi, no errors. But I can't catch these broadcasts.

Comment: Messaging app is system (manufacturer) signed app and has permission to listen those. And your app can't because that is not system signed or designed at framework level.

Comment: @mathew, I'm trying to do this as my phone sends an SMS to a number whenever I reboot my phone. I get charged for an SMS whenever I turn on my phone after a reboot.

Comment: @pankaj, is there anything that I can do to make it a system app?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281533/contentobserver-used-for-sms maybe this will help

Comment: @HarshaCAlva seriously your phone should not be doing that. Factory reset it. What phone is it?

Comment: i think it is possible. there are many sms apps alternatives, and there are also sms blockers apps.

Comment: @mathew, it's a legit number used by Samsung sim tracker. If I disable sim tracking, the SMS won't be sent. Nothing to worry.